# Designing a differentiator op amp with a maximum voltage gain and gain limiting frequency

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design, signal, ltspice

Hi I am required to design a differentiator for a project which requires a maximum voltage gain of 22 and a gain limiting frequency of 30kHz.

Heres my progress so far:

[image]

If im not mistaken (correct me if im wrong) Av=Rf/R1 which is already solved. However isnt a gain higher than 1 supposed to make the output signal larger than the input?

Also i am having trouble finding sources for the formula of gain limiting frequency.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Av=Rf/R1 only if Rf and R1 are the only two impedances in their respective paths. What about C1 and Cf?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy so is it safe to say that Av=Zf/Z1?

Comment: Zf/Z1 may give you a complex value, and if you don't mind Av being complex, then yes.

Comment: The maximum supply for OP07 is +/-18 V. It might work, but all bets are off. Then `Cf` is not needed if you're after an ideal differentiator. `R1` would also not be needed, but since you need a fixed gain, it is. Which means you'll have an opamp with `R1`, `C1`, and `Rf` determining the transfer function. It will be of the form \$K\frac{s}{s+\omega_p}\$, where K is the gain. It looks like a highpass and that's what it is, but a highpass is a differentiator until \$\omega_p\$.

Comment: If you need a true differentiator with 6dB/octave gain, this conflicts with your BW and gain limits with never achieving either at f max So the design must define the acceptable errors, such as phase or amplitude error vs f and true gain limits vs f